# Angular structural directive and Renderer2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives, angular-renderer2

I have a custom checkbox directive that adds styling in the traditional label/span style as well as some other functionality.  It injects the wrapper around itself and the span alongside.  I just realized that when placed in a structural directive it fails to manipulate the DOM.  Most of the setup is done in the constructor, but I'm thinking that maybe this needs to be more Angular life-cycle-aware to play well with structural parents.

Example issue DOM:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="test">
    <!-- <div class="row align-middle"> -->
      <input type="text" alloy placeholder="you should see a checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" alloy alloyLabel="default">
    <!-- </div> -->
  </ng-container>
```

With that commented div it works.  However, with the ng-container as it's direct parent the renderer fails to inject the DOM.  This is the constructor:

```
constructor(
    protected el: ElementRef,
    protected renderer: Renderer2,
    protected focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
    @Host() @Optional() protected identityDirective: AlloyIdentityDirective) {
    super();

    // If we don't have a label wrapper, create one
    this.labelElement = this.renderer.parentNode(el.nativeElement);
    if (!(this.labelElement instanceof HTMLLabelElement)) {
        const label = this.renderer.createElement('label');

        // Inject wrapper then move native element (input) within it.
        this.renderer.insertBefore(this.labelElement, label, this.el.nativeElement);
        this.renderer.removeChild(this.labelElement, this.el.nativeElement);
        this.renderer.appendChild(label, this.el.nativeElement);
        this.labelElement = label;

    // We must add the span because that's what actually gets the check styling
    this.styledElement = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.labelElement, this.styledElement);
}
```

### Edit: Added Resultant DOM

There is no actual error.  In the flawed case (direct parent of `ng-container`) I end up with the initial element, but no injections:
`<input type="checkbox" alloy alloyLabel="default">`

With the wrapper `div` I get the expected injections (_ngcontent* removed):

```
<label class="alloy-check-wrapper">
  <input alloy="" alloylabel="default" type="checkbox" class="alloy-check">
  <span></span>
  <span class="alloyLabel">default</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Couple of questions - does it error, or just fail to inject anything? Are the input elements present even though the directive does not output?

Comment: Good question, oversight on my part.  I'll add to the question.

Comment: Thanks... what is "outside" the <ng-container> tag? I have a feeling that this line: `this.labelElement = this.renderer.parentNode(el.nativeElement);` might be involved somehow... maybe the ng-container is somehow messing up or interfering with the parent node.

Comment: Yah, that was the first thing that jumped out at me, but I would suspect that it simply fails the if statement, which means the label is generated (in fact I think that if is overly cautious anyway).  However, the outer node in my test example is:
`<div style="max-width: 75rem; margin: auto;">`

Comment: I'm guessing that the constructor executes for the immediate children of the container at some earlier point in the life cycle other than when the ngIf becomes true... maybe moving the init logic to an ngOnInit would help? I'm not confident that's an answer but give it a go...

Comment: It's a good answer, exactly what I thought as well.  My first attempt was not successful, but I rushed it at the end of the day.  I plan on making a cleaner attempt this afternoon.

Comment: Can you put a debug break point on the constructor (e.g. in the Chrome Debugger) and let us know at what point in the page lifecycle the constructor is being executed? Is it when the ngIf becomes true or when the page loads?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179826/discussion-between-anthony-and-mark-hughes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be caused by the fact that when an element is at the top-level inside an ng-container, it gets constructed earlier than when your ngIf becomes true, i.e. before it is added to the DOM.

To fix this, you need to move your logic which is modifying the DOM from the constructor to ngOnInit, e.g.:

```
constructor(
    protected el: ElementRef,
    protected renderer: Renderer2,
    protected focusMonitor: FocusMonitor,
    @Host() @Optional() protected identityDirective: AlloyIdentityDirective) {
    super();
}

ngOnInit() {
    // If we don't have a label wrapper, create one
    this.labelElement = this.renderer.parentNode(el.nativeElement);
    if (!(this.labelElement instanceof HTMLLabelElement)) {
        const label = this.renderer.createElement('label');

        // Inject wrapper then move native element (input) within it.
        this.renderer.insertBefore(this.labelElement, label, this.el.nativeElement);
        this.renderer.removeChild(this.labelElement, this.el.nativeElement);
        this.renderer.appendChild(label, this.el.nativeElement);
        this.labelElement = label;
    }

    // We must add the span because that's what actually gets the check styling
    this.styledElement = this.renderer.createElement('span');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.labelElement, this.styledElement);
}
```

For modifying the DOM, this is almost certainly a better practice anyway as at the point the constructor executes, you can never say with certainty whether it is present in the DOM correctly or not.